# how can i bring this word? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

i study to openweathermap api.

want to bring weather to openweathermap..

API:

```
{"coord":{"lon":128.6811,"lat":35.2281},"weather":[{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":16.49,"feels_like":13.68,"temp_min":16,"temp_max":17,"pressure":1008,"humidity":31},"visibility":8000,"wind":{"speed":1.03,"deg":270},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1617013413,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5507,"country":"KR","sunrise":1616966191,"sunset":1617011007},"timezone":32400,"id":1846326,"name":"Changwon","cod":200}
```

i think haze is the weather..

but i bring that, it is fail.
my app said, ' type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index''
help plz

my code:

```
    class TodayWide extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map weatherData;

  const TodayWide({Key key, this.weatherData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 2),
        children: <Widget>[
          Todayweatherpanel(
            textColor: coyellow,
            title: '현재 온도',
            count: weatherData['main']['temp'].toString(),
          ),
          Todayweatherpanel(
            textColor: coyellow,
            title: '체감 온도',
            count: weatherData['main']['feels_like'].toString(),
          ),
          Todayweatherpanel(
            textColor: coyellow,
            title: '습도',
            count: weatherData['main']['humidity'].toString(),
          ),
          Todayweatherpanel(
            textColor: coyellow,
            title: '날씨',
            count: weatherData['weather']['main'].toString(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weather` in the api response is an array. If you want to access the first element in it do so with

```
final weatherMain = weatherData['weather'][0]['main'];
```

But preferably convert the json directly to a Dart class with a tool like https://app.quicktype.io/. This prevents your app from breaking whenever the api returns a different response.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you again, but could you put °C after the temperature?

Comment: You can store the value of `weather` in a variable like the example I posted. Then you're able able to create a formatted variable with the Celsius degree symbol. Something like

`final weatherMain = weatherData['weather'][0]['main'];
final formattedMain = '$weatherMain °C';
`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```dart
final type = weatherData['weather'][0]['main']; // prints 'Haze'
```